# pentaho sql connection: driver could not be found

Tags: sql-server, pentaho

> Driver class '`sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`' could not be found, make sure the 'MS SQL Server' driver (jar file) is installed.
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

Comment: The JDBC/ODBC Bridge has long been removed from Java. Use a native JDBC driver.

Answer (score 2):

1. download sqljdbc jar file from this [Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774)
2. place it inside `data-integration/lib` folder

Answer (score 0):

You got error because you don't have **sql connector driver**.
first download compatible sql connector , and place it in ***data-integration/lib*** folder then **restart** your pentaho tool
[You can get sql connector driver here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774)